# Controlling a CSS Animation with Buttons

Tags: html, css, animation, scroll

I need to have scrolling images controlled by two arrows (scroll up and scroll down). I have a CSS "scrollUp" animation written as well as a "scrollDown" animation. How can I have these animations occur to the images when the arrows are clicked?

I think I need to have a "scrollUp" class and a "scrollDown" class applied to the images. but I am not sure how to make one arrow activate the "scrollUp" class animation and another activate the "scrollDown" animation.

I've seen people use links with href="#something" to activate an ID animation, but my images can't have multiple ID's so that will not work.

Any help would be greatly appreciated! If you know of any video tutorials that would be great too! I'm not opposed to using JavaScript but I'd prefer to use CSS.

EDIT: I basically need the following code to activate one image at a time, whenever a button is clicked:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>web browsers</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    margin-left: 100px;
margin-top: 100px;
}
#header {
height: 256px;
width: 256px;
overflow: hidden;
border:1px solid gray;
}
.slider {
animation: myanimation 8s ease-in-out infinite alternate;   
}
@keyframes myanimation
{   
0% {transform:translateY(0px); }
25% {transform:translateY(-256px); }
50% {transform:translateY(-512px);}
75% {transform:translateY(-768px);}
100% {transform:translateY(-1024px);}               
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="header">
<img class="slider" src="img1.png" width="256" height="256">
<img class="slider" src="img2.png" width="256" height="256">
<img class="slider" src="img3.png" width="256" height="256">
<img class="slider" src="img4.png" width="256" height="256" >
<img class="slider" src="img5.png" width="256" height="256">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Would you be able to provide the code you already have?

Comment: Multiple CSS animations are simple to achieve but it's somewhat unclear what you're trying to achieve here.  Scrolling Images??  Do you mean like a slideshow or are you trying to scroll up and down the page?

Comment: I just added the code, I need that to occur one at a time using buttons. Sorry about not having it in originally

Comment: Still looking for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this issue by changing the method I used to actually scroll the images. I decided to instead use an iFrame with a hidden scrollbar. Javascript allowed buttons to control the iFrame's scrolling. Thanks to all that helped out!

Answer (score 0):

It wouldn't be the best solution syntactically, but you could wrap the image scroller inside of an `<input type="checkbox" id="scroll-up-control">` tag, then select against `#scroll-up-control:checked` to apply styles for scrolling up, with the default listed above for scrolling down.

I would use some simple javascript to just apply a class to the container with whether to scroll up or down though.